# Output defined variables in current session

Tags: osx, set

In the terminal I define the following variable:

```
TEST_MY_VAR="something"
echo $TEST_MY_VAR
# output: something
```

I expect this to be added to my current session. If I open a new terminal and try to use the same variable, as expected it returns nothing:

```
$ echo $TEST_MY_VAR
```

Now using [set](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html) I'm able to view all variables that can be used.

```
$ set
# returns ALL variables that can be used
```

Is it possible to show all the variables that are only of the *current session* and not all the others?

For example if I would like to know which one's I've set before in the current session.

---

**edit:**
*I've seen [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/420295/how-do-i-see-a-list-of-all-currently-defined-environment-variables-in-a-linux-ba) describe the use of `(set -o posix ; set)`. However that doesn't seem to work on the terminal of MacOS.*

Comment: Is this in bash?

Comment: I used zsh. And based on your comment also tried bash. But that gives me the message: `set: no such . option: posix` @Panki